# How to find the screen width and apply it to a particular css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to find the user screen width and needs to apply this width to a style.

I have a `container`.

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

I need to put the width into css using JavaScript or any other options.

How can I do this??
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Width of the screen? Or width of the document/window?

Comment: can you post the surrounding HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas  width of the document/window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the screen resolution use `screen` object:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.width = screen.width + "px";
```

To get the width of you browser window (for all browsers except IE6 and below, otherwise check [this cross-browser method](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/)) use:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
```

Also, pay attention that the script should be called only when the document is fully loaded.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DNPNz/

Comment: Getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: @Libin check if you are getting the element

Comment: The error gone when I place the js after container. but the width is not applying to the container.

Comment: @Libin Have you added "px" as in example?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your EDIT helped me. That `+ "px"` was missing in my code.

Answer (score 2):

For this **CSS media queries** is best. Write like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px)
 {
      #container{
        background: #ccc;
      }
    }
```

Check this for more http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this. the code below will help you grab the width or height for all browsers.

```
function getViewPortSize()
{
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    // Standard browsers
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
        viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight
    }

    // IE6
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
    {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    //Older IE
    else
    {
        viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }

    return viewportwidth + "~" + viewportheight;
}
```

to set width for container

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.width = your_width_Here;
}
```

make sure the container is loaded before the js. i think that's the correct syntax

Or

I think if you just want to div to fill the browser window width. you can just use css

```
#container { width: 100%; }
```